# Using a drawing library for making a GUI

Tags: c, user-interface, opengl, graphics, drawing

I'm working on a project and planning to use a drawing library(OpenGL) for the GUI. Is this frowned upon or considered bad practice?

I googled a bit about the topic and found only discussions about GUI libraries, and no information on whether using a drawing library for the GUI is bad or not.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you would be "re-inventing the wheel"

Here are some similar questions to yours.

[What disadvantages could I have using OpenGL for GUI design in a desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721802/what-disadvantages-could-i-have-using-opengl-for-gui-design-in-a-desktop-applica)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245643/opengl-gui-library?rq=1